# Debug mode stopped working in IDEA with Kotlin

Tags: java, debugging, kotlin, gradle

I have been working on a project for a while now and on one day I tried to run my project in debug mode and I got this error message:

```
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in C:\Users\myuser\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlinx\kotlinx-coroutines-core-metadata\1.3.8-native-mt-1.4.0-rc\5b54677a19ebb20ec7dac0d9e4dfc806df327df\kotlinx-coroutines-core-metadata-1.3.8-native-mt-1.4.0-rc.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I tried

- Invalidate cache and restart
- Reimporting the project
- Deleting the `.gradle` folder from the project **and** my HOME dir

but nothing helped.

What can I do to solve this? I did no code change that could make this happen, it was working a day ago.

Comment: This is a bug in the new Kotlin coroutine debugger. As a workaround please do in Intellij: "File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Kotlin | Disable coroutine agent".

Comment: Please add this as an answer, this works! Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a bug in the new Kotlin 1.4 coroutine debugger: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41175. As a workaround please do in Intellij IDEA: **File | Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Kotlin | Disable coroutine agent.**

The coroutine debugger is going to be disabled in MPP projects by default in Kotlin 1.4.10.

Comment: Coroutine agent is found at different place in Android Studio on Macbook. But anyways i used search in Preferences and found the correct place. This solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In some Intellij version : **File | Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger**

[image: coroutime location]